# Underscore js, object missing data

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

```
obj {column1{name:abc, items{price:10, count:5}, title:def}}
```

I have an object as above, the `count` has been added after an loop ajax succession to the object `obj`, I will then append the `obj` to the underscore template.

I did a console.log of the `obj` after adding `count` into the `obj` and it appears to be there. When I do a loop of `items` in the template, `count` seems to be missing. I did another console.log of `items` in the template and `count` is appears to be there.

Anyone knows the mystery of `count`?

```
$.each(rows, function(i, row) {
    $.each(row.items, function(i, item) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'route',
            data: { data: datapost },
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(num){
                item.count = num;
            }
        });
    });
});
$('#container').append(template(row));
```

the missing count in the template:

```
<% _.each(items, function(item) { %>
    <%= item.price %> <%= item.count %>
<%})%>
```

Comment: I'm afraid it will remain a mystery unless you show some example code that replicates the problem.

Comment: @Juhana i apologize, just did an edit.

Comment: I'm a bit confused; you're making an async call, but the code that doesn't work is sync? I mean, you need to wait for the call to complete before you start using data added in the callback.

Comment: @DaveNewton thanks mate, i understand how it works now. will be editing my codes